# Header and footer for a figure

Tags: floats, framed, wrapfigure

(I'm new to latex and don't know the right keywords to search.)
I would like to put a header and footer lines to my figures (floats), instead a framebox, since they sometimes takes longer than a whole page.

Any suggestions?

I want the result to look like:

[image]

Comment: i'm not sure i understand.  your description implies that some of your floats may be longer than a page.  that's not feasible -- a float must fit on a page; it can't be broken.  if this isn't correct, please describe a little more clearly exactly what you want.  if you *do* qwant something that can be broken, but is set off in a recognizable manner, then the package `mdframed` might help.

Comment: you are right. That is why I'm looking for some work around. my frames only contain a lot of text (specifically a descriptions of protocols). Instead of putting all the text inside a framebox I would like to only put a header at the beginning and footer at the end.

Answer (score 3):

With `tcolorbox`

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{covered}[1][]{%
    colback=white,hbox,
    blanker,
    boxsep=5mm,
    frame code={
        \draw[line width=2pt,blue] ([yshift=-5mm]frame.north west) |-
                (frame.north east) -- +(0,-5mm);
        \draw[line width=2pt,blue] ([yshift=5mm]frame.south west) |-
                (frame.south east) -- +(0,5mm);
        },
    width=\linewidth,
    nobeforeafter,
    #1}


\begin{document}
  \tcbincludegraphics[
          blanker,boxsep=5mm,hbox,finish={
          \draw[line width=2pt,blue] ([yshift=-5mm]frame.north west) |-
                (frame.north east) -- +(0,-5mm);
          \draw[line width=2pt,blue] ([yshift=5mm]frame.south west) |-
                (frame.south east) -- +(0,5mm);},
          graphics options={width=3cm}
          ]{example-image}

  \noindent
  \begin{covered}
    \includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image-a}
  \end{covered}
\end{document}
```

[image]